# How to remove Addclass node data in Dynatree

Tags: addclass, dynatree

I have a node relation with data of MySQL, inside this data have Visible field. When i take visible by default the node of dynatree is view in black, when uncheck visible view in gray.

I use this to set to gray:

```
$('#tree').dynatree('getTree').getNodeByKey('ID1').data.Addclass('nodegray');
```

How delete this nodegray class for a previous set to nodegray?

nodegray is defined like: `span.nodegraya { color:#666666;}`

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the problem assigning the `addClass` with gray or black depend on visibility like this:

```
if ($visible == 0)
    $('#tree').dynatree('getTree').getNodeByKey('ID1').data.addClass = 'nodegray';
else
    $('#tree').dynatree('getTree').getNodeByKey('ID1').data.addClass = 'nodeblack';
```

And next redraw the tree with:

```
$('#tree').dynatree('getTree').redraw();
```

Comment: if some answer is correct, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Comment: Also if you don't need to re-draw the whole tree, you can just redraw an individual node with `node.render()`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by selecting dynatree node class. Check the name of your dynatree nodes and do the following:

```
$('#tree').find('.yourNodeClass').removeClass('nodegray');
```